# TP Link TL-WN722NC (Atheros AR9271L) monitor mode and packet injection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, wireless-card, packet-injection

I was looking for a USB wireless card for my android phone with NetHunter installed (since my current one doesn't support monitor mode and packet injection) that supports monitor mode and packet injection.

I found [this](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N): TP Link TL-WN722NC.

It has an Atheros AR9271L chipset.

I was wondering if it supports monitor mode and packet injection, as I can not find any clear information myself.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wikidevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Wireless_adapters/Chipset_table) and [ath9k htc](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Ath9k_htc), the TL-WN722NC has AR9271L chipset with `ath9k_htc` Driver support the monitor Mode and the Packet injection.

```
Supported modes
STA (Station) mode: supported
IBSS (Ad-Hoc) mode: supported
AP (Master) mode: supported
Mesh (802.11s) mode: unsupported
P2P mode: supported
Monitor mode: supported
Packet injection: supported
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the response. I don't know how I managed to miss that :)